# How to change default KeyInfo generated by Apache CXF 4.0.0

Tags: java, xml, soap, cxf

I create request to SOAP service using Apache CXF. In my xml payload I have this part:

```
>  <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-247c2b79-9a61-42ea-822e-e5e23e9132f0">
>                 <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
>                         xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
>                         xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
>                         wsu:Id="STR-b87ecccc-604a-4851-8331-3aef53d99661">
>                     <wsse:KeyIdentifier
>                             EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
>                             ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">
>                         ZrB9tQsoAOkiwFiAAMSG87/T8bg=
>                     </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
>                 </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
>             </ds:KeyInfo>
```

and I nedd to change ValueType to http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3 because my binary token needs it. How can I overwrite it?